# How to make the program waits till the command is executed

Tags: c++, shell, command

I'm trying to execute a system command throught a program then wait till the process is terminated to carry on executing code's instructions. I've been using `sleep()` but it didn't work out because it was relative i mean execution time differs from machine to another ...so is there any solution for this?

Consider code below(language==c++):

```
ShellExecute(0, "open", "cmd.exe","/C rasdial adsl user pwd", 0, SW_HIDE); //can also use system().
Sleep(sec);
if(CheckConnection()) {cout <<"U r connected"; }
```

Wait till system command is executed to check for connection (I think you get now).

Comment: Does MSVC++ support the `system` function? If so, you can do `system("cmd.exe /C rasdial adsl user pwd")`

Comment: yah it supports that ...but the problem is i dnt want to get the output of execution

Answer (score 6):

Use ShellExecuteEx instead of ShellExecute, and then call WaitForSingleObject with the hProcess you receive:

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFO info = { sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO) };
// fill in values in SHELLEXECUTEINFO as necessary
if (ShellExecuteEx(&info))
{
    WaitForSingleObject (info.hProcess, INFINITY);
    // The new process has now completed
}
else
{
    // Launch failed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `CreateProcee` you have more options see this example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682512(v=vs.85).aspx to wait program accomplishment with `WaitForSingleObject`

Comment: This is great solution ..thnx

Comment: i dont know why i keep getting error
CreateProcess failed (2). (even using code given by microsoft)

Comment: @user2355950 could you please extend result of `GetLastError` with `FormatMessage` (as it's used in example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679351%28v=VS.85%29.aspx bellow the page) and let me know what the error you see.